VLC video package not playing in flutter application
I am making a flutter desktop application which plays a video and it does not play it simply loads on screen.
Developing a Flutter desktop application that includes video playback functionality. However, the video does not play as expected. Instead, it appears to be stuck in a loading state, indicating that the video is not playing but only loading on the screen.
enter image description here
this is my code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/flutter_vlc_player.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  late VlcPlayerController _videoPlayerController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
    // Initialize the VlcPlayerController
    _videoPlayerController = VlcPlayerController.network(
      'https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4',
       hwAcc: HwAcc.full,
      autoPlay: false,
      options: VlcPlayerOptions(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Dispose of the controller when the widget is disposed
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black, // Replace with your desired background color
      body: Center(
        child: VlcPlayer(
          controller: _videoPlayerController,
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          placeholder: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

and this is the error :
A Dart VM Service on Windows is available at: http://127.0.0.1:57747/YU3k4HyQ7K0=/
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
#0      VlcPlayerApi.initialize (package:flutter_vlc_player_platform_interface/src/messages/messages.dart:632:7)
<asynchronous suspension>

this is my pub file
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  file_picker: ^8.0.6
  video_player: ^2.9.1
  flutter_vlc_player: ^7.4.2
  video_player_control_panel: ^1.1.1
  video_player_win: ^2.3.9
  sprintf: ^7.0.0

I am making a flutter desktop application which plays a video and it does not play it simply loads on screen.
Developing a Flutter desktop application that includes video playback functionality. However, the video does not play as expected. Instead, it appears to be stuck in a loading state, indicating that the video is not playing but only loading on the screen.I am making a flutter desktop application which plays a video and it does not play it simply loads on screen.
Developing a Flutter desktop application that includes video playback functionality. However, the video does not play as expected. Instead, it appears to be stuck in a loading state, indicating that the video is not playing but only loading on the screen.I am making a flutter desktop application which plays a video and it does not play it simply loads on screen.
Developing a Flutter desktop application that includes video playback functionality. However, the video does not play as expected. Instead, it appears to be stuck in a loading state, indicating that the video is not playing but only loading on the screen.

In AndroidManifest.xml Add this:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<activity
    android:resizeableActivity="true">

<meta-data
     android:name="android.allow_multiple_resumed_activities"
     android:value="true" />

In Your HomeScreen Change this:
autoPlay: true,

